# copy sheet to text file with specific template skips even numbers

Tags: excel, export, text-files, vba

I want to copy sheet to text file with specific template, I defined a range but the problem is it skips even numbers it means rows A2, A4,A6... not copied
so it brings at the end of the result empty rows

```
Option Explicit

 Sub txtFile()

  Dim strPath As String
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim ts As Object

   Dim wsDest As Worksheet
   Set wsDest = Sheets("Filter FS")
   wsDest.Select
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Dim cellAimsID As Variant
  Dim cellAmount As Variant
  Dim cellCurrencyISO As Variant
  Dim cellReason As Variant
  Dim cellExpiryDate As Variant
  Dim FirstRow As String
  Dim LastRow As String

  Dim a As Range, b As Range, cell As String, rng As Range
  Set a = Selection
  Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\cben\Documents\BKC\FinancialSecurity\test13.txt", True, True)
  ' for each cell in the worksheet create a line in text fil
 FirstRow = wsDest.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row
 LastRow = wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = wsDest.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
 'Set rng = wsDest.Range("A1:A5")
  For Each a In rng
    cellAimsID = a.Cells(a.Row, 1)
    cellAmount = a.Cells(a.Row, 2)
    cellCurrencyISO = a.Cells(a.Row, 3)
    cellReason = a.Cells(a.Row, 4)
    cellExpiryDate = a.Cells(a.Row, 5)

    'AimsID, Amount, Currency, Reason, ExpiryDate are the name of columns in worksheet
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "cases" & ": [")
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "{")
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "AimsID:" & cellAimsID & ",")
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "Amount:" & cellAmount & ",")
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "CurrencyISO:" & cellCurrencyISO & ",")
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "Reason:" & cellReason & ",")
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "ExpiryDate:" & cellExpiryDate & ",")
      ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "}" & ",")

  Next
 ts.Close

End Sub
```

here is the result

[image]

for exemple AimsID= 69210794 correspond to A41 next AimsID =86917526 corresponds to A43 not A42 in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your `For Each` loop as detailed below.

```
  For Each a In rng
    cellAimsID = a.Cells(a.Row, 1)
    cellAmount = a.Cells(a.Row, 2)
    cellCurrencyISO = a.Cells(a.Row, 3)
    cellReason = a.Cells(a.Row, 4)
    cellExpiryDate = a.Cells(a.Row, 5)
```

In this loop, the variable `a` refers to a `Range` object. Yet, inside of the loop, you assign to each variable a `Range` property of a `Range` object. Let's take a closer look as an example:

```
`cellAimsID = a.Cells(a.Row, 1)
```

Let's assume you are on the second iteration of the loop, and the variable `a` refers to cell `A3`. The syntax above says `cellsAimsID = Range("A3").Range("A3")`. What happens when we apply a `Range` property to a `Range` object? It basically offsets cell. In that above example, the cell pointer essentially moves to a cell that would be the third cell in Column A IF the range started with A3.

I know that sounds a bit confusing, but follow up if you have questions.

To fix the error, replace the syntax with (notice I removed the `a` qualifier):

```
cellAimsID = Cells(a.Row, 1)
cellAimsID = Cells(a.Row, 1)
```

As a side note, it is a good practice to fully qualify your ranges with a sheet name in case your macro ever does processing on different sheets. So it would be *even* better to change the code to:

```
cellAimsID = wsDest.Cells(a.Row, 1)
cellAimsID = wsDest.Cells(a.Row, 1)
```

Comment: I was confused, but I trusted you and it works, I will take a time and understand it later, thank you @user35611813

Comment: @BKChedlia Consider marking the question as answered so that other users know the problem is resolved. On a side note, it looks like you're trying to parse your spreadsheet into a `JSON` type of format. If this is the case, it may be syntactically incorrect since you open `Arrays` but don't close them. Follow up with a new question if this is the case.

Comment: ts.Close doesn't close this arrays ?

Comment: @BKChedlia ts.Close closes the text file. In your ouput, you write: `cases:[{AimsId:69210794,...}` The `[` character opens an array, but the array is never closed using a `]`

Comment: I understand you, I made a close ] , for the lastrow , I will Add the last updates. Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is my code after changes, 
It allows the export of a worksheet in text file with specific template.
PS : Last line have a close Array so I did it outside the range.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub txtFile()

  Dim strPath As String
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim ts As Object

   Dim wsDest As Worksheet
   Set wsDest = Sheets("Filter FS")
   wsDest.Select
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Dim cellAimsID As Variant
  Dim cellAmount As Variant
  Dim cellCurrencyISO As Variant
  Dim cellReason As Variant
  Dim cellExpiryDate As Variant
  Dim FirstRow As String
  Dim LastRow As String
  Dim LastRowB As String
  Dim a As Range, b As Range, cell As String, rng As Range, Lastrng As Range
  Set a = Selection
  Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\cben\Documents\BKC\FinancialSecurity\test20.txt", True, True)
  ' for each cell in the worksheet create a line in text fil
 FirstRow = wsDest.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row
 LastRow = wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 LastRowB = (wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) - 1
 Set rng = wsDest.Range("A2:A" & LastRowB)
 Set Lastrng = wsDest.Range("A" & LastRow)
  ts.WriteLine ("{")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“cases”" & ": [")
  For Each a In rng
cellAimsID = Cells(a.Row, 1)
cellCurrencyISO = Cells(a.Row, 2)
cellAmount = Cells(a.Row, 3)
cellReason = Cells(a.Row, 4)
cellExpiryDate = Cells(a.Row, 5)

'AimsID, Amount, Currency, Reason, ExpiryDate are the name of columns in worksheet

  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "{")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“AimsID”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellAimsID & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“Amount”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellAmount & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“CurrencyISO”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellCurrencyISO & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“Reason”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellReason & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“ExpiryDate”" & ":" & Chr(9) & "“" & cellExpiryDate & "”")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "}" & ",")

  Next

cellAimsID = Cells(LastRow, 1)
cellCurrencyISO = Cells(LastRow, 2)
cellAmount = Cells(LastRow, 3)
cellReason = Cells(LastRow, 4)
cellExpiryDate = Cells(LastRow, 5)

  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "{")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“AimsID”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellAimsID & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“Amount”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellAmount & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“CurrencyISO”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellCurrencyISO & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“Reason”" & ":" & Chr(9) & cellReason & ",")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "“ExpiryDate”" & ":" & Chr(9) & "“" & cellExpiryDate & "”")
  ts.WriteLine (Chr(9) & "}" & "]")
  ts.WriteLine ("}")
 ts.Close

End Sub
```